# Whenever I commit, it links to my another github account's username

Tags: git, github

For some reason, I had to use my personal and official github user account in the same machine. After this, whenever I commit from my local git to github, the name of the user is my another account's username. I dont understand how this account is still linked to my local git. I've checked the username in git but that username is different than my github username.

Suppose my github account1 user name is **Max.** Account2 username is **Ron**. And my local git name is **Maxron**. But whenever I tried to push something on account1, it uploads the commits with the username of account2.

i did check the git username via
`git config --global user.name`
it shows the name MAxron

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you use a git tool such as Source Tree or Git Kraken? It is easy to manage such configs with them.

Comment: Github uses email to link commits to authors. So check `git config [--global] user.email` and check your commits with `git log --format=fuller`. Also verify you have added proper email addresses to Github accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Check the remote setting for the repository.

`git remote -v`

Will show you where you're pushing to.

Comment: i did check, pushing to the correct right directory but with the wrong github username

Comment: What is in your: ~/.gitconfig file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `user.name` in your local configuration:

```
git config --local user.name
```

Comment: it's empty in my case

Comment: I imagine it's worth setting email too

Comment: Try to set it to your desired user and commit to check. Normally it should pick the global one if it's not set.

Comment: not it's not even taking the global one name. It simply takes the another accounts github user

Comment: Can you check your local git config file: `.git/config`. Do you see any `[user]` property there?

Comment: What do you mean when you said: " it uploads the commits with the username of account2." Did you check the commits using the `git log` and found a different username from the one you expected to have?